# Shortcut to reload page in Chrome without re-POSTing data

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

In Chrome, is there a keyboard shortcut to reload the current URL with a GET request, regardless of whether data was just POSTed to the page or not? I would like to do what the <kbd>F5</kbd> key does after you've first requested a page. If there's an option to tell Chrome to never re-POST a request upon Refresh, that would be sufficient.

I can't find an answer to this question through Google, but perhaps it's because I'm not asking it correctly. I realize you can obtain this functionality by clicking the address bar (a shortcut for which is is <kbd>F6</kbd>) and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I'm just wondering if there's another way.

Comment: In Chrome 75, I now have to hit Enter two or three times in the address bar to trigger a fresh GET request when I haven't changed the address.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know another keyboard shortcut, but what I do is drag the page icon from the address bar and drop it anywhere in the page. It will reload the page just like the first time.  It  may be faster than finding the F6 key.